# Clang++: define data type at linking

Tags: templates, llvm, clang

is there any possibility to compile C++ programs into LLVM assembler and define the type of some variables at link time?

Consider this small programm

```
template<typename T> T inc(T v) {return v++;}
```

When you compile it, it won't be compiled into bitcode, because it is a templated function.
But I cannot `#include` it in my source code files, because I want to create several bitcode files and link some specific ones at runtime of my program.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: It doesn't exist until instantiated with a concrete type — what exactly do you want to link?

Comment: I'm creating a Numerical solver. Depending on the options specified in Python, specific solvers (and data types) should be used and linked together into a binary program.

Comment: Well, if you want to use C++ templates then you need to use C++ frontend, or explicitly instantiate for types you need (so the appropriate linkable functions get generated). There is nothing to link with, if you don't.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not possible with C++ templates. But perhaps there is a different solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the answer is no, you can't.  But you could link to the clang libraries and instantiate+compile the routines directly from C++ at runtime.